# How to get north south east and west values from latitude and longitude using HERE API?

Tags: here-api

using this HERE API:
https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=200%20S%20**Lodhi%20Colony**%20CA&app_id=***&app_code=####
I am able to get all info about Lodhi Colony. Similarly I want to pass input as lat and long and want it's north south and east west values.

Example:

Input:

Lat = 41.02633002010979
Long = -111.94550019690477

Output:
 "mapView": {
        "west": 2.33073,
        "south": 48.86836,
        "east": 2.33347,
        "north": 48.87016
      }

I tried to use info provided here(https://developer.here.com/c/geocoding) but I'm not able to use it.

**Edit : **
I want bounding box of given latitude and longitude.

Comment: The two APIs (linked in your first and last paragraphs) are different - if you want the bounding box, use the API which returns it

Comment: Thanks @AdamHopkinson for instant response but I don't want to draw bounding box, I just want to convert Lat and Long to N, S and E W values

Comment: The lat/lng _is_ n/s/e/w. If the latitude is + it's north and - is south, and if the longitude is + it's east, - is west. So your example is 41.xxx N -111.xxx West. What the mapview data is giving you in your example is a bounding box to draw a map.

Comment: @AdamHopkinson thanks for explanation, I want bounding box of coordinate. Can you guide me how to get it suing python?

Comment: I've said above that if you want the bounding box, you can use the API you've linked to - you then said you didn't want the bounding box.

All a bounding box is is the original coordinates with a little added/removed - how much depends on how big your map is and how zoomed in/out you want it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the help of other stack-overflow answer, I figured it out by myself without need of any API.

```
import math
latitude = 41.02633002010979
longitude = -111.94550019690477
offset = 1.0 / 1000.0;
latMax = latitude + offset
latMin = latitude - offset

lngOffset = offset * math.cos(latitude * math.pi / 180.0)
lngMax = longitude + lngOffset
lngMin = longitude - lngOffset

print("latMax = "+str(latMax), "latMin = "+str(latMin), "lngMax = "+str(lngMax), "lngMin = "+str(lngMin) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below example to use geocoding API for a bounding box specifics.
With mapview parameter, you can assign x,y appropriately that can form a box on the map.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/geocoder/latitude-longitude-by-mapview-parameter